# Copula Models for Asset Returns

Tags: time-series, finance, copula

I'm learning about copulas and their applications in finance. When used to assess the dependence structure between two indices for example, can the copula models be estimated directly on the log-returns or should they undergo, that is the log-returns, some transformation then estimating the copula models on the said transformation?

Comment: Since the copula is the distribution function of the indices AFTER they have been transformed to uniform distributions, this does not matter at all.

Comment: Dear @g g, thank you for your reply. If I understood correctly, no transformation should thus be applied to the log-returns when estimating the copula function using for example a statistical software such as "copula" package in R because the transformation to a uniform distribution is already done when calling the function.

Comment: @KhalilBelghouat "*[...] transformation to a uniform distribution is already done when calling the function*", this is dependent on what method you use in the `fitCopula` function (if you intend to use this package). This is also specified in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/copula/copula.pdf). In order to circumvent any future *coding* problems (odd results), it will be a good idea to read the documentation and the corresponding [paper](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v021i04) of the package :-).

Comment: Thank you so much @g g, very well understood! And I apologize for taking from your time.